# To change the variable from one main method to another main method

Tags: java

I have to keep this server.start and server.stop code in main class also i have to call a class from a shell Script  which in turn  can change the status of flag.
Problem is whenever i do that status of flag is not changed in A class and loop never terminates.I have also tried volatile keyword  with flag but no benefit.

```
public class A {
  static boolean flag; 

  public static void main (String args){
    server.start()
    waitforShutDown();
    server.stop()
  }

  public static void waitforShutDown() {
    while(!flag) {
      Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
  }

  public static void shutDown() {
    flag=true;
  }

}

//from this class i wll call for shutDown()

public class B {

  public static void main (String args[]) {
    new A().shutDown();
  }
}
```

Comment: please format this code.

Comment: Code without proper indentation is hard to read so please format it properly (don't forget to put it in code sample - `{}` button on editors menu). Also please ask clear and specific question.

Comment: What do you think a `main` method is or does? Why do you think so?

Comment: main method lets JVM to enter into code , also a memory allocation is done inside JVM i think that is why class B is not able to change value of flag in class A

Answer (score 0):

A program in Java can only have one main method. Therefore class B will not be executed. You might consider using threads or instantiating class B in class A.